# visual studio asp.net project requiring password if started over rdp

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, rdp

If I connect to my development machine via RDP and work with an asp.net solution, I have to enter my username and password for opening the projects web site (from within the rdp session). If I do the same localy on the development machine, no password is required.
The only solution to avoid this strange behaviour, is to **deactivate NTLM-authentication** in the project start options.

What is the reason for this strange behaviour? What is the difference when I use VS2010 in remote session instead of a local session?

Comment: Can you tell me where in the project build settings are you able to deactivate NTLM-authentication please?

Comment: @Barry: Sorry, It's in the start options, not in the build options. I have corrected my question.